# In react router, how can we build authentication based routes?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, react-router, react-redux

In react router, how can we build authentication based routes?

Assume that we want some routes needs specific authentication, let's say authTypeA, to access, and some routes needs more authentication, let's say authTypeA, authTypeB, authTypeC together.

Then how can we make these in react router(v2)?

Answer (score 0):

```
const Routes = (
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route component={requireAuth(['authenticated'], ['/trade'])}>
    <Route path="/dualview" component={TradingViewContainer} />
    <Route path="/marketdata" component={MarketDataContainer} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/signin" component={SigninContainer} />
</Route>
);
```

We can use HOC(higher order component) to build authentication based route which manages access the path after checking the authentication.

In react router v2, you can define  within the higher order component that has a authentication logic.

```
export default function(strategies = [], greenRoute = []) {
  class Authentication extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = { allGreen: true }
    }
    componentWillMount() { // When access the route with first time
      const { history, location } = this.props
      if (greenRoute.indexOf(location.pathname) === -1) {
        strategies.map((strategy) => {
          if (!this.props.auth[strategy]) {
            this.setState({ allGreen: false })
            history.replace(`signin?next=${location.pathname.slice(1)}`)
          }
        })
      }
    }
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      const { history, auth } = this.props
      if (greenRoute.indexOf(location.pathname) === -1) {
        strategies.map((strategy) => {
          if (!nextProps.auth[strategy]) {
            this.setState({ allGreen: false })
            alert(I18n.t('auth.needSignin'))
            history.replace(`signin?next=${location.pathname.slice(1)}`)
          }
        })
      }
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      const { location } = this.props
      if (prevProps.location !== location) {
        return true;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < strategies.length; i++) {
        return prevProps.auth[strategies[i]] !== this.props.auth[strategies[i]]
      }
    }
    render() {
      return this.state.allGreen ? this.props.children : (<div></div>)
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      auth: state.auth
    }
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication)
}
```

Above code, you can make a logic that when this.state.allGreen is true, then render this.props.children which the component you want to access.

In requireAuth component (HOC), **componentWillMount** will break in to access the specific component which needs authentication, and check whether it has the authentication state, then decide whether to be accessed or not.

And, the **componentWillUpdate** can be used when the authentication state is changed so that accessing component will be denied.

**shouldComponentUpdate** will be used for performance.

This code is built on the library react, react router, redux.

Feel free to use!

Answer (score 0):

In react-router, you can give a function which will run before entering a route. There, you can make your validation and redirect in case of problem. Check this example. Hope it's answering you

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { IndexRoute, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router';
    import App from './App';
    import { getToken } from './main/services/cookie';
    import Navigation from './main/navigation/Navigation';
    import * as authenticationActions from './authentication/actions/authenticationActions';

    export default (store) => {

      const performAuth = async (nextState, replace, callback) => {
        const authenticated = store.getState().authentication.authenticated;
        const token = getToken();

        if (!authenticated) {
          await store.dispatch(authenticationActions.authenticate(token));
        }
        callback();
      };

      const requireAuth = (nextState, replace) => {
        const authenticated = store.getState().authentication.authenticated;
        if (!authenticated) {
          replace({ pathname: Navigation('login') });
        }
      };

      const checkAuth = (nextState, replace) => {
        const authenticated = store.getState().authentication.authenticated;
        if (authenticated) {
          replace({ pathname: Navigation('schedule') });
        }
      };

  const languages = ['en', 'fr'];

  return (
    <Route onEnter={performAuth}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} >
        <IndexRoute component={Login} onEnter={checkAuth} />
            <Route path={Navigation('login', language)} component={Login} onEnter={checkAuth} />
            <Route path={Navigation('schedule', language)} component={PersonalSchedule} onEnter={requireAuth} />
            <Route path={Navigation('profile', language)} component={Profile} onEnter={requireAuth} />
      </Route>
      <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
    </Route>
  );
};
```